# How to check if a record exists for the same date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case, sql-view, case-when

I want to check if a record exists in same table for the same account and on same date.Here is the case statement am using it in my view

```
CREATE VIEW TEST AS
    SELECT 
    T1.DATE,
    T1.ACTNBR,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE T2 WHERE T2.ACTNBR = T1.ACTNBR AND T2.DATE = T1.DATE)
         THEN calculation1
         ELSE calculation2
    END CAL_COLUMN

    FROM TABLE T1
```

When this CASE returns boolean , i want calculation1 to executute else calculation2 should execute.

Looks like the above CASE WHEN EXISTS statement will check for all the dates and all the acct numbers in the table instead it should check for that particular row date and account number.
Can we initiate a variable(before executing the select statement) and store the date of that record being checked and reinitialize for every row.

Comment: Your view would seem to do what you intend.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read up on [how to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to optimize this by minimizing the number of times the inner select is executed? Or do you want to do a one-time update across the table to store the calculated results in that table?

Comment: @Ram Your observation seems to be wrong, the exists will execute per row in T1.

Comment: @Fact Yes, you are right. I thought inner query will match for all the dates in outer query.And we noticed this later. I am at basic level in sql.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if below helps:

```
create table tttt(dt date, actnbr int);
 insert into tttt values('2018-01-01', '1'); 
 insert into tttt values('2018-01-01', '1'); 
 insert into tttt values('2018-01-01', '1'); 
 insert into tttt values('2018-01-01', '3');


 SELECT 
  T1.dt,
  T1.ACTNBR,
   sum(1) over(partition by T1.ACTNBR, T1.dt order by T1.dt) as RecordsCount   
   FROM  tttt t1
  ;

 2018-01-01,1,3
 2018-01-01,1,3
 2018-01-01,1,3
 2018-01-01,3,1
```